# Dart ffi NativeCallack must be of subtype

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I'm working on a Dart project that needs to call a dylib in Linux and receive a callback via a function pointer. All functions that call into the library are working as expected but I can't get the callback to work and there is very sparse information available to help find the problem.

```
typedef EventHandlerFunction = UnsignedInt Function(UnsignedInt inEvent, UnsignedInt inPropertyID, UnsignedInt inParam, ffi.Pointer<Void> inContext); 

UnsignedInt handleStateEvent(UnsignedInt inEvent, UnsignedInt inPropertyID, UnsignedInt inParam, ffi.Pointer<Void> inContext) {

  return const UnsignedInt();
}

final callback = NativeCallable<EventHandlerFunction>.isolateLocal(handleStateEvent, exceptionalReturn: 0);
```

This appears to match the only examples I've found but I get the error:

```
The type 'UnsignedInt Function(UnsignedInt, UnsignedInt, UnsignedInt, Pointer<Void>)' must be a subtype of 'UnsignedInt Function(UnsignedInt, UnsignedInt, UnsignedInt, Pointer<Void>)' for 'NativeCallable'
```

The required type matches the specified type so I'm stumped as to what the problem is. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I'm confused... What are the imports of your source file? You have `UnsignedInt` and `ffi.Pointer`. Surely they'd both be prefixed - or neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleStateEvent` function needs to look like a Dart function with real Dart types. (It can't have the 'dummy' native types since they aren't real Dart types. In particular, you get a clue that it's wrong when you see `return UnsignedInt();` since you can't instantiate an `UnsignedInt` yourself.

Change your method to:

```
int handleStateEvent(
  int inEvent,
  int inPropertyID,
  int inParam,
  Pointer<Void> inContext,
) {
  return 123;
}
```

When you implement the body of the function, just use the 3 `int` parameters naturally. Access `inContext` the normal way for `Pointer`s