# Flutter Dart C library binding type error after ffi:gen

Tags: c, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I got `C library` which was generated to binding via [ffigen](https://pub.dev/packages/ffigen). I need to integrate it to my `Flutter` app. I added generated `.dart file` to my project and it has these types:

```
typedef emetryhub_bluetooth_ctx_t = ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void>;

typedef emetryhub_bluetooth_destroy_cb_t = ffi
    .Pointer<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Int32 Function(emetryhub_bluetooth_ctx_t)>>;

external emetryhub_bluetooth_destroy_cb_t destroy_cb;
```

I am trying to define this C `destroy_cb` callback function in my Dart code

```
  Int32 destroyBluetooth(emetryhub_bluetooth_ctx_t ctx) {
    return 0 as Int32;
  }

  bluetooth.ref.destroy_cb = Pointer.fromFunction(destroyBluetooth);
```

and it gives me an error:

```
The type 'Int32 Function(Pointer<Void>)' must be a subtype of 'Int32 Function(Pointer<Void>)' for 'fromFunction'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that a C->Dart callback? Please update the question showing the relevant C header that you generated from.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083477/dart-ffi-nativecallack-must-be-of-subtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Dart callback implementation from:

```
  Int32 destroyBluetooth(emetryhub_bluetooth_ctx_t ctx) {
    return 0 as Int32;
  }
```

to

```
  int destroyBluetooth(emetryhub_bluetooth_ctx_t ctx) {
    return 0;
  }
```